# jQuery array displaying separation commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I have the following jQuery array, with the HTML code for multiple images stored in it:

```
var images = [ "my first image's code, second image's code, etc, etc" ];
```

I then have them displayed like so:

```
$('.gallary').prepend(''+images+'');
```

This works perfectly, except for one thing; the commas (,) which separate the image codes within the array show up on the site between the displayed images. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show your actual code for `images` and what you want exactly.

Comment: do you have a single string in the array as above? Or is it an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If comma is your problem, it is so because when an Array is typecasted to String, `Array.join` gets called, which joins with default separator, which is a comma `,`

So you've to manually add a empty separator, if you don't want them and you can safely remove those extra string quotes.

```
$('.gallary').prepend(images.join('')); // should remove the ,
```

Comment: @Joie then please do accept my answer by clicking the tick mark if it helped. Also glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are other ways that should work wore efficiently:

[ADORABLE DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/ccbcbf1bb469fea81ebf15232cb9c0dd)

```
var images = ["<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>",
              "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>",
              "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>",
              "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>"].join('');
// with jquery
$(images).appendTo('.gallery');
```

plain js is fast too:

```
// equiv to `$(images).appendTo(thing);`

document.querySelector('.gallery').innerHTML += images;
```